# Convert map [[entries]] to object (javascript)

Tags: javascript, angularjs, object

I have a map, and in console I can see this:

```
[[Entries]]

{"val1" => Array(3)}
{"val2" => Array(3)}
```

I need convert this map to an object to use it in ng-repeat (AngularJS), but how? Thanks a lot.

Comment: Do you know how to iterate over a map?

Comment: do you have a map of type Map or is it an object at first place?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Array.from` to get an array of `[key, value]` from the map and then reduce to create an object from it.

Something like this should work:

```
Array.from(map).reduce((acc, [key, value]) => {
    acc[key] = value;
    return acc;
}, {});
```

However, if the keys are something other than a string, they will be converted to strings as javascript objects only have string keys.